# Make a variable a coordinate in xarray

Tags: python, coordinates, python-xarray

I need to turn a variable (that has two dimensions) into a dimension (replacing one of the existing dimensions) - basically, remapping the dataset along a different set of basis functions than before, or, I guess changing the coordinate system without changing anything else about the dataset.

Basically, using a sample dataset:

```
import xarray as xr

# Define a sample dataset
ds = xr.DataArray(np.random.randn(2,3),
             dims = ['forecast_time','lead'],
             coords = {'forecast_time':[0,1],
                       'lead':[0,1,2]}).to_dataset(name='v1')

# Get a new variable that's a combination of the two coordinates
ds['time'] = ds['forecast_time'] + ds['lead']

# Make the variable a coordinate
ds = ds.assign_coords({'time':ds.time})

print(ds)
```

[image]

However, I need `v1` to instead have dimensions `time`, `lead`.

Does anyone have any advice? I've gone down some rabbit holes with stack/unstack and assign_coords, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

So one way to do it is through a for-loop in a new empty dataset:

```
import numpy as np

ds0 = xr.Dataset(data_vars = {'v1':(['time','lead'],
                  np.zeros([len(np.unique(ds['time'])),
                            *[ds.sizes[k] for k in ['lead']]])*np.nan)},
                 coords = {'time':(['time'],np.unique(ds['time'])),
                           **{k:([k],ds[k].values) for k in ['lead']}})

for lead in ds.lead:
    for ftime in ds.forecast_time:
        ds0['v1'].loc[{'lead':lead,
                       'time':ds.sel(lead=lead,forecast_time=ftime)['time']}] = (ds.sel(lead=lead,forecast_time=ftime))['v1']
```

This works, but can be slower for really large datasets (and isn't super 'pretty'). If anyone has a more elegant solution, I'll keep this answer open!

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `groupby`:

```
def forecast_time_to_time(dataset):
    result = dataset.swap_dims(forecast_time="time")
    return result


ds.groupby("lead").apply(forecast_time_to_time)
```

yields:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:        (time: 4, lead: 3)
Coordinates:
  * time           (time) int64 0 1 2 3
    forecast_time  (lead, time) float64 0.0 1.0 nan nan nan ... nan nan 0.0 1.0
  * lead           (lead) int64 0 1 2
Data variables:
    v1             (lead, time) float64 -0.7022 -1.711 nan ... -1.523 -0.09927
```